@OneToOne or @ManyToOne on Instrument.created references an unknown entity: user.User where User is interface
I have following error:
@OneToOne or @ManyToOne on Instrument.created references an unknown entity: user.User

User class is public interface with abstract methods. The only class which is implementing User is CommonUser which is annotated with @Entity and @Table(name="users").
So yes, error is correct - User is not an entity but I don't want it to be because CommonUser is an entity.
What should be the correct approach here?
Do I need to change code to make Instrument class work on concrete CommonUser, not User?

Yes. You have to work with CommonUser otherwise hibernate don't know how to handle this link.

no other way? The only solution is to change User to CommonUser in Instrument class? This change force next code changes. Really it can be done in different way?

No. Hibernate doesn't know how to load User. Why do you even have it if it have only one implementation?

Not sure, maybe in past there were more classes implementing User interface and were removed and only this one stayed. Anyway, thank you for help, accepting answer!
